# Is there any way to pass url params to Page Tab App?

Tags: javascript, facebook, arguments, parameters

I am using Javascript SDK

In the documentation it says that the params passed in url will be placed inside the 'app_data' key inside the 'signed request' JSON object. You can find this explanation in the bottom of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

On this page, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/
It says that "For certain types of apps, a signed request is passed to the app which contains some additional fields of information, even before Permissions have been requested."

I've made a Page Tab app, and I cannot get 'signed_request' object. It should be a key inside the 'response' object that you get by calling FB.getLoginStatus(), but this is all I get as a response object {authResponse: undefined, status: "not_authorized"}

So there is no 'signed request'. What should I do?

Comment: You aren't using any server side code to deal with facebook? The thing is, the signed request is posted to your page, so on your server side you can read the posted data and there you could find the app_data

Comment: I'm using Javascript SDK, and in the docs it says that I can access 'signed_request' variable, same like I would in PHP sdk for example. I'll try with PHP sdk today and I'll post results.

Comment: Yes, accessing the app_data parameter only works server-side, because it is only included in the signed_request you get POSTed to your app on initial load. The signed_request you get from getLoginStatus is different, and only gives you info related to the actual login process.

Comment: Correct. I've tried PHP SDK and I do get signed_request param even when the user didn't authorize the app. So this works